# Has anyone created a homegrown source control add-in for NAV that uses Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial, fogbugz, kiln, dynamics-nav

We use Mercurial for our source control for C# and Progress code.

We are now developing in Microsoft's Dynamic NAV.  There is no built-in source control and it's awkward (and error-prone) to manually put code in/out of our Mercurial repository for versioning.

I was wondering if anyone has developed an homegrown, integrated source control system for NAV using Mercurial.  What were the steps and what advice/ideas can you share?

Comment: Are you just using basic Mercurial or are you using an interface to it like Kiln or something similar?

Comment: Yes, we have it integrated with Kiln and Fogbugz.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could put together some scripts to automatically export and import from C/SIDE to TXT files, combined with "hg add" / "hg update".

If you're on NAV 2013, then you can export by [running finsql.exe with the ExportObjects command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh166064%28v=nav.70%29.aspx). I don't think this works directly on earlier versions, but you can probably do something similar with the [EXPORTOBJECTS function in app code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd983800.aspx). There is corresponding functionality for importing.

[This post on Waldo's blog](http://dynamicsuser.net/blogs/waldo/archive/2009/06/05/exporting-and-importing-objects-with-c-side-in-nav-2009.aspx) might also be interesting. He also has many other posts which are relevant, as he is from the team behind [Revision](http://www.ifacto.be/en/revision), an integration between NAV and TFS.

Comment: This is VERY cool.  Thanks for the links.  This may be enough info for us to put something together.

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark the answer as closed if you consider it answered :-)

Comment: Your ideas are good and I appreciate them.  I was still hoping for more input before I mark this question as answered.